# How to Skip 1st line of file - awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am beginner to awk.
I have created one file which contains employee information.
There are employees in different departments. And i wanna count that how many employees in each department.
like

```
marketing        3
sales            3
production       4
```

For that i used following command.

```
awk 'NR>1 {dept=$5} {count[dept]++} END {for (dept in count) {print dept count[dept]}}' emp
```

But above code it count and displays the first line i.e header also.
like

```
marketing 3
sales 3
department 1
production 4
```

where department is a header of column which is also counted although i used NR>1..
And how to add space or increase the width of all columns.. because it looks like above output.. but i wanna  display it properly..
So any solution for this?

Here is my input file

```
empid       empname     department
101         ayush    sales
102         nidhi    marketing
103         priyanka    production  
104         shyam    sales
105         ami    marketing
106         priti    marketing
107         atuul    sales
108         richa    production
109         laxman    production
110         ram     production
```

Comment: Show your input file. Also try `NR>1{count[$5]++}END{yadayda}`

Comment: oh thnx it works..  and how to increase the width of the columns..

Comment: @Dip Show an example input file. Otherwise it is just guessing for others.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [GNU printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html#Format-Modifiers) for proper tab-spaced formatting

```
awk 'NR>1 {count[$3]++} END {for (dept in count) {printf "%-15s%-15s\n", dept, count[dept]}}' file
```

You can use `printf` with `width` options as below example if `printf "%3s"`

- `3`: meaning output will be padded to 3 characters.

From `man awk`, you can see more details:

```
width   The field should be padded to this width. The field is normally padded
        with spaces. If the 0  flag  has  been  used, it is padded with zeroes.

.prec   A number that specifies the precision to use when printing.  For the %e,
        %E, %f and %F, formats, this specifies the number of digits you want
        printed to the right of the decimal point. For the %g, and %G formats,
        it specifies the maximum number of significant  digits. For the %d, %o,
        %i, %u, %x, and %X formats, it specifies the minimum number of digits to
        print. For %s, it specifies the maximum number of characters from the
        string that should be printed.
```

You can add the padding count as you need. For the input file you specified

```
$ awk 'NR>1 {count[$3]++} END {for (dept in count) {printf "%-15s%-15s\n", dept, count[dept]}}' file
production     4
marketing      3
sales          3
```

Comment: it will give tab between two fields ..  i wanna increase width

Comment: will you please tell me exactly where to place NR in any code/query?

Comment: You can google it a bit, some examples here, http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/118605-awk-whats-nf-nr.html

Answer (score 18):

You can use tail to skip a specific number of header lines. Here is an example:

```bash
command | awk  '{print $1}' | tail -n +2
```

This will skip the first line after performing awk on the first column of the command result.

Comment: Nice and simple +1